# CakePHP HABTM Filtering

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've got two tables - `users` and `servers`, and for the HABTM relationship, `users_servers`. Users HABTM servers and vice versa.

I'm trying to find a way for Cake to select the servers that a user is assigned to.

I'm trying things like `$this->User->Server->find('all');` which just returns all the servers, regardless of whether they belong to the user.

`$this->User->Server->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Server.user_id' => 1)))` just gives an unknown column SQL error.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table names are right. There are many ways to do this:

**Use the Containable behavior**

In your AppModel, set the following:

```
 var $recursive = -1;
 var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then, use the following code to query your servers:

```
$userWithServers = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => 1),
    'contain' => array('Server')
));
```

Note that we are querying the User model, instead of the Server model to accomplish this.

**Use bindModel**

```
$this->Server->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('UsersServer')));
$this->Server->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Server.*'),
    'conditions' => array('Server.user_id' => 1)
));
```

I personally don't recommend using bindModel a lot. Eventually, your code becomes a bit unmanagable. You should try using the Containable behavior whenever possible. The code looks cleaner and simpler. More on the bindModel method can be found [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM).

HTH.

Comment: The containable behavior was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to name tour table user_servers.

Comment: Looking at the Cake manual I think that my approach should work? `This new join table's name needs to include the names of both models involved, in alphabetical order, and separated with an underscore ( _ ).`